# Android: Why does makeText work with Toast instance?

Tags: android, android-toast

I accidentally coded my Toast this way and it continues to work.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

  private Toast mToast;

  ...

  private void onClickHandler(int itemIndex) {
    mToast = new Toast();
    mToast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(itemIndex), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```

Given that makeText is a static method, why would the above work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because static methods and variables can also by accessed from an instance of the class

However, accessing them that way is considered bad practice

Comment: Yep, that and Android Studio is one of the IDEs that highlights it as a suggested change as opposed to a compile error when using Java. Better yet, Kotlin doesn't tolerate using static methods from instances at all.